# Merge two sheets and keep the redundant data

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup, worksheet-function

I have two Excel sheets. First one is like this:

```
folk_id name first_name town_name
001     blog joe        alamo
002     folk james      brisbane
003     paco yatan      barcelona
```

Second one is like this:

```
folk_id music_instrument  color
001     banjo             blue
001     guitar            green 
001     piano             yellow
002     harmonica         grey
003     harpsichord       red
003     violin            orange
003     bass              fuschia
```

Results would be like this (either in the same sheet or a different one):

```
  folk_id name first_name town_name music_instrument  color
  001     blog joe        alamo     banjo             blue
  001     blog joe        alamo     guitar            green
  001     blog joe        alamo     piano             yellow
  002     folk james      brisbane  harmonica         grey
  003     paco yatan      barcelona harpsichord       red
  003     paco yatan      barcelona violin            orange
  003     paco yatan      barcelona bass              fuschia
```

I've tried with `VLOOKUP` and `INDEX` but I'm bit confused on how to do it.

I'm looking for a formula and not VBA.

Comment: So, to be clear, you are trying to populate the second sheet with the appropriate data from the first?

Comment: Hi @choirbean, yes. There will be redundancy but that's ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copy second sheet, insert three columns between `folk_id` and `music_instrument` (assuming four columns in the source, might actually be only three) then use a lookup function to populate the added columns. Assuming `folk_id` is then in A1, in B1:

```
=VLOOKUP($A1,Sheet1!$A$1:$D$4,COLUMN(),0)
```

copy across and down to suit.

Comment: @Pnuts wow I over complicated my answer, this is much cleaner and simpler

Comment: @pnuts Eh, I will leave it up for reference sake I guess, I feel though that  more versatile approaches to index and match are probably covered in other answers on the site

Comment: You save my life, pnuts. IOU.

Comment: On my way to becoming a sifu , me too. :)

Answer (score 0):

This answer covers how to do this on a third sheet.  For simplicity lets call each sheet Sheet1, Sheet2, Sheet3

Sheet1 and Sheet2 contain your current data.

The first step is to make a reference in Sheet3 that copies the entire column of `folk_id`.  Because it seems `Sheet2` contains the larger amount of `folk_id` and Sheet1 contains the unique values of `folk_id` you need to copy `Sheet2`.  To do this just simply call `=Sheet2!A2` starting in `A2` of Sheet3, and just auto fill down.

Now for each column in where data lies in Sheet1 we will perform the index and match.  While for data that is in sheet2 you only need to have reference calls.

### Sheet1 Data Referenced using Index and Match:

1. Name column:
   `=INDEX(Sheet1!B:B,MATCH(A2,Sheet1!A:A,0))` starting in cell  `B2` and autofill down.
2. first_name column `=INDEX(Sheet1!C:C,MATCH(A2,Sheet1!A:A,0))` starting in cell  `C2` and autofill down.
3. town_name column `=INDEX(Sheet1!D:D,MATCH(A2,Sheet1!A:A,0))`  starting in cell  `D2` and autofill down.

### Sheet2 Data Referenced normally:

1. music_instrument column: `=Sheet2!B2`  starting in cell  `E2` and autofill down.
2. color column: `=Sheet2!C2`  starting in cell  `F2` and autofill down.